# How to recover from loss of connection to a (locally hosted) DCOM object?

Tags: vb.net, dcom

(I'm not sure if this is would be better suited for code review)

I'm using a (closed source) library that maintains a DCOM connection internally, this DCOM connection goes to a service running on the local machine. This service is stopped and started quite frequently by the user (not through our application).

Unfortunately it looks like DCOM related exceptions bubble up to our application.

There doesn't seem to be any way given in the library to determine if the connection to the service is still valid, right now the only way to know we've lost connection to the service to try to do something and have it throw an exception (the type of which varies significantly).

My best attempt to try to make this a little more manageable is to separate out exceptions that are usually caused by DCOM from exceptions that are caused by configuration problems....

Here's a sample of what the code ended up looking like:

```
Private Sub Initialize()
    Dim ParametersToDComObject As Integer

    Try
        Dim HRESULT = ClassThatUsesDCOMInstance.InitDCOMObject(ParametersToDComObject)
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to service through DCOM.")

    Catch Ex As Exception
        If (IsLikelyCausedByConnectionLoss(Ex)) Then
            'in this case, throw to make sure that we don't try to continue assuming that the connection went through

            'I'm not sure what type of exception would be best to throw here,
            'this would occur if the service is not running; the calling function
            'would notify the user that there's a problem
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(Ex.Message, Ex)

        Else
            Throw


        End If

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub ReadDataFromClass(EntryName As String)
    Try
        Dim HRESULT As Integer = ClassThatUsesDCOMInstance.ReadEntry(EntryName)

    Catch Ex As Exception
        If (IsLikelyCausedByConnectionLoss(Ex)) Then
            'If the service is stopped, from the application's perspective every method in 
            'this class suddenly starts failing, and it won't start working again until a new instance 
            'of the class that uses DCOM is made.
            '
            'So the sub below attempts to make sure that our application knows that the methods in this class
            'won't work anymore... (I usually set ClassThatUsesDCOMInstance to Nothing after cleaning up)
            '
            'Sometimes I just have to "reconnect", but the tricky thing is, the only recovery option may be to
            '(re)start the service that's providing the DCOM object; it seems best to notify the
            'user in this case since in most cases the user knowlingly stopped the service, it's
            'normal to stop the service to configure it
            CleanupAfterConnectionLoss()
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(Ex.Message, Ex)
        End If

        If (TypeOf (Ex) Is TheLibraryDefinedThisException) Then
            'let's say that the library throws this if we try to read an entry that doesn't exist (e.g., if the configuration has changed)
            'we can't fix the problem automatically, but we can notify the user that something has changed external to this program, so they can
            'either fix the service or edit their configuration for our application
            Console.WriteLine("Entry " & EntryName & " could not be read " & Ex.Message & " check that the entry is defined on the service")

        Else
            Throw

        End If

    End Try
End Sub




Private Function IsLikelyCausedByConnectionLoss(ThrownException As Exception) As Boolean
    'I'm thinking it's best to put this in a separate function because development has gone like this:
    '
    ' 1. the provided documentation does not give any information about what methods will throw what kinds of exceptions
    '    All functions return **HRESULTs**, I assumed that there weren't going to be /any/ exceptions
    '   
    '   It turns out the HRESULTs cover certain errors and exceptions cover certain errors, with some overlap...
    '
    ' 2. I determined experimentally during testing that it throws a <Library Defined Exception> if I give it an invalid entry name, okay, I can work with that
    '
    ' 3. I determined experimentally that if I stop the service while we're connected, all functions throw a COMException, not convenient but ok.
    '
    ' 4. Weeks later, I figure out that it also occasionally throws InvalidComObjectException if the service is stopped under the same situation
    '
    ' 5. Weeks later, I find out that it occasionally throws ApplicationExceptions under the same situation
    '
    ' 6. Weeks later, I find out that certain functions will additionally throw an InvalidCastException
    '
    ' note that there's no change in input to the library to cause these different exceptions, and the only cause
    ' is the loss of connection to the DCOM server
    '
    ' in the last code setup I had to manually update every try/catch block that had anything to do with this library every time
    ' I found something new...

    If (TypeOf (ThrownException) Is InvalidCastException) Then
        'I really don't like catching this, but I get this if the COM object fails to bind to the interface,
        'which occasionally happens if the service isn't there or isn't set up right
        Return True

    ElseIf (TypeOf (ThrownException) Is ApplicationException) Then
        'I really don't like catching this either, same reason as above
        Return True

        'I don't believe this is an exhaustive list of every exception that can be thrown due to loss of DCOM connection,
        'please let me know if you know of more exceptions that can be thrown...

    ElseIf (TypeOf (ThrownException) Is Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) Then
        Return True

    ElseIf (TypeOf (ThrownException) Is Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException) Then
        Return True

    Else
        Return False

    End If

End Function
```

I feel like this is a poor solution for the problem, though. It seems better than just swallowing all exceptions but not by much.

- Is there any exception that encompasses all possible DCOM errors?
- Alternatively, is there some other way to detect that a connection to a service has been lost?

EDIT:

- Is this situation typical for DCOM in .NET?

Comment: If your program cannot meaningful continue without the DCOM component being functional then there is no point whatsoever in catching the exception.  Yell as loudly as possible before you terminate, the only good way to educate that user and to stop him from messing with that service.

Comment: @Hans Passant Good point, and it might end up being the solution; I hesitate to do that because stopping and starting the service is sometimes the only way to add and remove entries, which is something the user will have to do. Plan B is to "strongly suggest" that the user not edit entries on the service while our application is running.

Comment: ...also, as tricky as this is, in theory the application can meaningfully continue if I make it so that it bypasses everything to do with this class (using CleanupAfterConnectionLoss()) until the user says the service is back up. The DCOM object is important but it's not needed for everything you can do with the program.